# Get HttpSession Before Timeout

Tags: session, jboss

Is there a way that I can configure JBoss so that I can get sessions before they expire? I know that when I shop on some websites, if I leave my shopping cart and don't checkout, after a while I get an email asking me to come back, so I'm guessing that they somehow get a hold of sessions before they expire and possibly persist them in the database.

Can someone explain how that works? Is there a JBoss setting, or something programmatic?

Answer (score 1):

There's an `HttpSessionListener`.  This ties in to the life cycle of sessions.

You can implement the `sessionDestroyed` method, which gives you one last chance to act upon the session before it's destroyed.

At this point you can pull stuff out of the session to generate your emails or whatever you want to do.